# Combining Composite and Mediator Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, composite, mediator

I've seen few attempts of implementing such a combination. But my question  is if combining these two Patterns is somehow recommended. As it seems to me that the Mediator, by controlling the behaviour of Conposite components, may disrupt the responsibilities logic of the Composite tree itself. May someone tell me if it is wrong and in case what is the good rationale of combining them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ow, we must be creative to think how to merge these two. Let me give it a try ;)

Considering that (in very brief description):

- **Mediator** controls how a set of objects interact;
- **Composite** treat objects and compositions of objects (generally recursive approach);

The combining of both patterns could result in a **Menu** object.

For instance, a menu renderer object should **mediate** the construction of an *Android* or iPhone menu (in a *Xamarin*, for example), or a HTML Menu (a *bootstrap* or *JQuery* based one)

So, while *mediating* method calls to render menu according to platform, it also should **compose** recursively the menu with each items and its respective childs.

Hope I could help ;)

Comment: Thanks Marcos. That's useful ineeed. You mentioned some creativiness efforts. May I argue that you would not think to such a combination as a first solution in managing communication between components? In my design, by the way, components are loop elements.

Comment: Indeed. The menu was a - fast - first try! ;)

What else can we think about it? How about calculator? A mediator orchestrating calls and treating arithmetic expressions as Composites.

The calculator is a long shot, but let's think - or at least try to - about some other practical application.